# Got InvalidOperationException when trying to access post data in custom filter

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I am developing asp.net core web application. When i try to access post data in custom filter, like this:

```
public class CustomFilter : Attribute, IAsyncActionFilter
    {

        private ActionExecutingContext _context;

        public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
        {
            _context = context;

            var dict = _context.HttpContext.Request.Form.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value.ToString()); // got error her

            //int id = dict[“id”];
...
```

I got this exception

> InvalidOperationException: Incorrect Content-Type: application/json.

I use `XMLHttpRequest` to sent data to server. Here is configuration:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open(“post”, url, true);

xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/jso

xhr.send(JSON.stringify(dataToSent));
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I'm stuck in exactly the same error 

Answer (score 1):

If you POST `application/json` body (with valid JSON inside) you cann't treat it as form data (which is usually `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`). Read raw body and deserialize it:

```
public class CustomFilter : Attribute, IAsyncActionFilter
{
    public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context,
        ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        var stream = context.HttpContext.Request.Body;

        string json = new StreamReader(stream).ReadToEnd();

        //Foo obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help. I have tried this code, but StreamReader(stream).ReadToEnd, returns empty string.

Comment: @Angy,  usually it means the body is empty or needed header is missing =) Could you check your POST request? `Content-Type` and `Content-Length` headers should be set. You could use https://requestb.in to ensure that.

Comment: I checked contet-type and content-length with debugger, in context.HttpContext.Request  and content-type is "application/json", content-length : 135

Comment: @Angy is it possible to access the body in controller? For example with `[FromBody]string value` action parameter.