# '_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Form' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-6.0, angular13

I am calling DotNet 6 based API from Angular 13. I have injected IHTTPContextAccessor in my business layer and also specified the dependency in Startup.cs file. But I am getting following exception

> '_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Form' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' Incorrect content-type: application/ json

I am unable to fix the issue. Any pointers would be highly appreciated.

Controller Code

```
 public IActionResult SubmitBid(JobBidView jobBidView)
    {
        var jobBidDto = _mapper.Map<JobBidDto>(jobBidView);

        var result = _jobManager.SubmitBid(jobBidDto);

        if (result.Message == JobBidConstants.BidSubmitted)
        {
            var response = _jobManager.SendEmailToClient(jobBidDto);
            _logger.LogDebug($"email notification sent}");
        }

        return Ok(new SubmitBidResult { error = result.Error, Message = result.Message });
    }
```

BL Code

```
public ResultModel SubmitBid(JobBidDto jobBidDto)
    {
        var resultModel = new ResultModel();
        if (jobBidDto.JobId != Guid.Empty)
        {
            jobBidDto.Job = GetJobById(jobBidDto.JobId);

            if (jobBidDto.Id != Guid.Empty && jobBidDto.JobId != Guid.Empty)
            {
                if (_httpFileHandler != null)
                {
                    var httpFiles = _httpFileHandler.GetFromFiles();

                    if (httpFiles.Any())
                    {
                    }
                }
            } 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Got InvalidOperationException when trying to access post data in custom filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44112969/got-invalidoperationexception-when-trying-to-access-post-data-in-custom-filter)

Comment: _" I have injected IHTTPContextAccessor in my business layer"_ - personally I think that your error happens here, in general BL should not operate with `IHttpContextAccessor`. As for concrete issue - can you please add code of action invoking the BL? And BL itself.

Comment: I have modified my code and including a few methods. The IHTTPContextAccessor is injected via Constructor in BL

Comment: The code you have shown doesn't show any use of _httpContextAccessor. Did you look at the link I've posted? Based on the error message it seems like you are sending application/json to your back end but they you try to access the request data from the Forms property.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The data is being sent using application/json but at the backend, it is being retrieved using Forms property. Actually, this application is being ported from MVC to Angular. So, I need to change the Forms object

Comment: Really you should just use the framework the way it was intended and allow the model binder to convert the request body into an object for you.

Comment: As per the suggestions given in the article shared by you, StreamReader(stream).ReadToEnd() is empty for me whereas the Content-Type and Content-Length headers are properly set, so, not sure why its not working.
BTW, content-type is application/json and content-length is 159